# yii2 custom error message for 'minHeight' rule

Tags: php, yii2

Here is my rule

```
        [
            ['photo_1','photo_2','photo_3','photo_4','photo_5','photo_6'], 
            'image', 
            'skipOnEmpty' => true,
            'minHeight' =>  '281',
            'minWidth' =>  '281',
            'extensions' => 'png, jpg, gif',
            'wrongExtension' => 'Faqat .png, .jpg, yoki .gif formatidagi rasmlarni yuklashingiz mumkin!',
        ],
```

How can I write custom error message for 'minHeight' and 'minWidth' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `underHeight` and `underWidth` keys (just like you used `wrongExtension`).

Available placeholders:

- `{attribute}`: the attribute name
- `{file}`: the uploaded file name
- `{limit}`: the value of $minWidth (or $minHeight)